# How to store some tags in Laravel and how can I technically store those tags using the same ID

Tags: php, laravel, migration

My question is that is okay to do it  ID or some integer in migrations and how to store multiple tags using the same ID in controllers?

Storing like this (storing multiple tags on the same ID): 
ID      TAG 
1      LARAVEL 
1     PHP

```
  Schema::create('table_test', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string("tags")
        });
```

Comment: I saw that in the migration file you created a table called table_test with two columns id and tags. 
Do you want to save multiple tags to that table  in the following type ? 

 laravel, PHP, web

Comment: @Chung
No I want to save it like this

ID   TAG
1      LARAVEL
1     PHP

Comment: Why do you want the tags to have the same ID?

Comment: @Chung Yes please, You may look my updated content
And that ID that is created I Want to use in another table

Comment: I just wonder why you want to do that ?

Comment: @Chung Because all those tags that are stored in a table in a distinguished ID I will use in another table which is Posts, and in that row it will be stored the ID of the tags table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the reason why you want to save the tags with same id in that table, but technically we can do that.

To create a unique id for each time you insert. I recommend you use uuid

```
   Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->string('tags');
   });
```

For each time when you insert, generate the uuid first

```
    // Generate uuid  
    $uuid = Str::uuid();

   // Insert to DB 
    DB::table('tags')->insert([
        ['id' => $uuid, 'tags' => 'Laravel'],
        ['id' => $uuid, 'tags' => 'PHP']
    ]);
```

Comment: I wanted the ID to be stored  dynamically that for each insert to be different ID